# Tensorflow Object Detection API validation vs test set

Tags: python, api, object, tensorflow, detection

I recently started looking into the [Tensorflow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detection) and have a question on the validation set:

Is the validation used at all for the model training?

For instance are the weights of the model selected based on the accuracy on the validation set?

I am trying to figure out whether I need to have an independent test set (different from the evaluation set) to get unbiased results on the model performance, or can use the validation set for that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The validation dataset (the test.record ) is not used in the training.
It is always better to have a validation dataset, to prevent overfitting for example.